# Grant Read access to service principal to get ONLY subscription ids on Azure

Tags: azure, api, rbac, azure-service-principal, read-access

I have over 50 Azure subscriptions under same tenant. I have created a service-principal under Azure active directory and provided the service principal 'reader' role to each subscriptions. When I make an API call from Postman I get all subscription ids but my concern is I am giving 'READ' access to all my resources on different subscriptions. I want to limit this service-principal will ONLY be able to list the subscription ids and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to limit this service-principal will ONLY be able to list the
> subscription ids and nothing else.

With "Reader" role, a user would be able to read all resources inside a subscription and not just subscription id.

I believe the solution to your problem is to create a custom role (let's call it `SubscriptionPropertiesReader`) and then give only the permission to perform read operation just at the subscription level. Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources), I believe the permission you would want to include in this role is `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/read`.

The challenge obviously will be to create this custom role in each and every subscription and then assigning this role to your Service Principal in each subscription.